# how NOT to store submit button value as post data php

Tags: php

ok i have dynamically created form elements with unique names and when validated i want to store all the form data into SESSION. 
This is the code to do it:

```
if(isset($_POST["address_submit"])){
  insertSessionVars();
  header("Location: http://localhost/project%20gallery/notes.php");
  exit;
}

function insertSessionVars(){
  foreach($_POST as $fieldname => $fieldvalue){
    $_SESSION['formAddresses'][$fieldname] = $fieldvalue;
  }
}
```

This works almost fine but stores also submit button value. I output it like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['formAddresses'] as $value){

    echo $value;

}
```

Any help will be greatful :)

Comment: Conditionals are useful: `if(something)...`

Answer (score 5):

Don't assign a `name` attribute to your submit button. If you assign a name then it is passed as part of the `$_POST` array.

```
<input type="submit" value="My Button" />
```

Since you no longer have the submit button in post, instead of checking if the submit button is set check to see if the post array contains data using `count()`.

```
if(count($_POST) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST values are just array so after the for each why don't you use unset to drop the submit key from the array

That way you can check the form has been submitted and the either choose to not set the submit key or drop it rather then not giving it a name at all

Answer (score 0):

Either way you can in your foreach do something like this (see *) and pass "$except" as parameter. 
Where $except has to be the name of your submit button in insertSessionVars();

- `if(!in_array($key, $except)){...}`

And ofc above your foreach something like this :

```
if(!is_array($except)) $except=array($except);
```